# Keeping temporary files after quiting WinSCP

Tags: temporary-files, winscp

I set the WinSCP temporary directory on my hard-drive, but after quitting WinSCP the files stored there get deleted.

Is it possible to prevent them from being deleted? So I can edit them or copy them later.

And if its possible, can WinSCP automatically load those files, if they are newer than the ones on the server? This is optional, but it would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to prevent them from being deleted?

Yes, the option is named [*Keep temporary copies of remote files in deterministic paths*](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_storage).

> Can WinSCP automatically load those files, if they are newer than the ones on the server?

WinSCP has function [*Keep remote directory up to date*](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_keep_up_to_date) that monitors local folder and automatically uploads any changes to the server.

If you run two instances of WinSCP, you can combine these two features, but it's quite strange setup.